# How to load data automatically from database on page load, using simple javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a server on nodejs and on the client side I am using simple javascript.
When a user access a particular page, I have to fetch the data from the database and need to show it in the table.
I do not want a button functionality, but just some thing which loads my data or call my function automatically, when the page loads.

```
//Global variable:

<script>var userCommands = {}</script>


//For Fetching the data from database, I used this function:

<script>
    function  getUserRecords() {
              var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    userCommands = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                    myCreateFunction();
                }
              };
              xhttp.open('POST', '/getuserhistory', true);
              xhttp.send("loggedinUser=" + loggedinUser);

    }
</script>

//For loading a table, its not finalised, but will do this way using the data loaded in userCommands:           

<script>
    function myCreateFunction() {
                var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                var header = table.createTHead();
                var row = header.insertRow(0);
                var cell = row.insertCell(0);
                cell.innerHTML = "CellC";
                var cell = row.insertCell(0);
                cell.innerHTML = "CellB";
                var cell = row.insertCell(0);
                cell.innerHTML = "CellA";   
    }
</script>
```

Comment: please share your code, what you tried

Comment: Kindly see my edited post, I have added the code. On page load, I need to  automatically call the function getUserRecords() and save the data in userCommands  and then use the myCreateFunction()   to create the table.

Answer (score 0):

You are in need of a tutorial, please visit www.Nodeschool.com click tutorials. Once you complete those learn the difference between the client side javascript and the server side. The server should be handling the data and sending it in a response. In that route on your server is where you handle the DB.users.find() etc... Or related database command.